# Is there a name for this class of k-homogeneous measures?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

For a subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ write
$$
  cS = \{ cs\; |\; s\in S \},
$$
and define $F_c$ for a measure $\mu$ as
$$
  F_c\mu(\Omega) = \mu(c\Omega) 
$$
for all $\Omega\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$, where $\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2)$ are the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am looking for information about the following set of measures
$$
   \mathcal{M}(k) = \{ \mu\in\mathcal{M} \; | \; \forall c\in\mathbb{R},\Omega\in\sigma(\mathbb{R}^2):\, F_c\mu(\Omega)=c^k\mu(\Omega) \}.
$$
Usually a function that satisfies
$$
  f(cx) = c^kf(x)
$$
is called $k$-homogenous. So I am tempted to call $\mathcal{M}(k)$ the set of $k$-homogenous measures. However, I have not been able to find information about this set (I keep ending up at homogenous metric spaces). Is there a name for this set so that I can look find more information about them? Or is there a book about this kind of measures?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there exists literature on this definition, yet I think the family of these kinds of measures should be quite restrictive. Let us denote $A=\mu(B(0,1))$, where $B(0,1)$ is the ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$ .For natural numbers $n$ $D(n):=B(0,\frac{1}{2^n})\setminus B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$ and denote $B=\mu(D(0))$, furthermore note that $D(n)=2D(n+1)$. Then we have,
\begin{align*}
A=\mu(B(0,1))&=\sum_{n}\mu\left(B(0,\frac{1}{2^n})\setminus B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})\right)\\
&=\sum_{n}\mu\left(D(n)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n}\mu\left(2^{-n}D(0)\right)\\
&=B\sum_{n}(2^{-n})^k\\
&=(1-\frac{1}{2^k})A\sum_{n}(2^{-n})^k
\end{align*}
Showing that $1=2^k\left(\sum_{n}(2^{-n})^k\right)$; does this equation in $k$ have many solution?

Comment: I have a feeling there is a mistake in the definition of $D$ as $B(0,\frac{1}{2^n}) \subset B(0,\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$.

Comment: I fully agree with the idea that these measures are quite restrictive.